# How to calculate heat dissipation improvement when adding a fan to the heat sink?

Tags: power-supply, heatsink, fan

I'm using an LM338 which I want to supply at least 3A @ 20V, with Vin being 35V.

I made my calculations and I figured out I'd need a very expensive (for my budget) heat sink so I'm looking for a more affordable solution, like attaching a fan to a cheaper one.

But how much (in numbers) does a fan affect a certain heat sink dissipation? How can I calculate this improvement from the datasheets?

Comment: Or more affordable like dropping the LM338 and replacing it with a buck regulator?

Comment: that's ridiculous, for that application just go straight to a buck regulator. burning 15V at 3A is 45W.. if you want a really cool heater in addition to your application, go for it, it will work great!

Comment: You can get Automotive grade buck converters for $1 which do up to 40V input, and adjustable to supply 20V, and you may find a 3A output but it's possible that you will need an external switch controller - and get a 60V rated MOSFET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dissipating at least 45W in your regulator, which is a lot.

Assume you have the TO-3 package (the TO-220 simply won't work at ambient `25C` no matter what heat sink you use) with a theoretical operating die temperature of `125C`. Computing the allowable thermal resistance to `25C` ambient:

\begin{align}
\Theta_{JA} = \frac{125-25}{45} = 2.22 \frac{C}{W}
\end{align}

However, the TO-3 package version has a `1C/W` resistance from the die to case, so you only get `1.22C/W` for the heat sink. Heat sink manufacturers will usually give you a specified value of what the thermal resistance to ambient is for force and natural convection.

For example, [this heat sink](http://www.wakefield-vette.com/Portals/0/resources/datasheets/641.pdf) specifies `0.9C/W` at 250 LFM (linear feet per minute), which is adequate for this application. There is also a plot of what the thermal resistance vs. air flow speed is, and it looks like roughly 125-150 LFM is the minimum flow speed you can have to maintain the device temperature below 125C.

However, this is running the device at it's limit, and is completely impractical. Even with the specified `0.9C/W` thermal resistance, you're going to get an `85.5C` rise above ambient, meaning your junction temperature is `110.5C`. That's stressing the device way too much.

I would take the suggestions in the comments and use a buck regulator instead of a linear one.

As a side-note, I'm not sure why you are complaining about the heat sink cost. The TO-3 package LM338 is ~$50 unit price, while I could find a heat sink with `0.5C/W` @250 LFM thermal resistance for ~$20 unit price. A buck regulator solution is significantly cheaper, and if you really need the linear regulator stability, then add a linear regulator after the buck regulator. Now there's only 10W dissipated in the linear regulator so you might be able to get away with either no heat sink and just use a fan, or just have a heat sink with no fan.

To actually calculate these values is beyond the scope of this answer... needless to say, for any complex geometry you will need to use CFD software.

Comment: Did I miss something in my math? I calculate 1.15C/W for the required heatsink, assuming junction temp at 125C and Tamb =25C and junction-case thermal resistance as 1C/W.

Comment: I'm pretty sure [100/45=2.22](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=100%2F45). I have no idea how you ended up with 1.15C/W...

Comment: This is from a book I have. It's an example. I followed a similar approach. http://i.stack.imgur.com/eocVY.png

Comment: Our differences are in that I seperated the heatsink and the junction resistance, and you counted them as one. Regardless, the difference in our calculations is 0.07. I'm just curious where that 0.07 went or came from.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the the approaches are identical. I would double check your numbers. Solving equation 2.5 gives \$R_{SA} =\frac{T_J-T_A}{P_D} - R_{JC}\$, and plugging in numbers gives \$R_{SA} =\frac{125-25}{45} - 1 = 1.22 C/W\$

Comment: I ran the numbers again, 1.22. I don't know what happened. Derp.

Answer (score -1):

You need thermal mass, not an expensive heatsink. you need a flat, preferably polished surface that will conduct heat out. copper and aluminum work better, but if its big enough, you can use steel. If you really wanna be thrifty, go to your local thrift store and find cheap large metal objects to sink the heat from your regulator. if its not a portable device you may be able to attach it to something which can act as a heatsink.

Comment: With more thermal mass all that will happen is it will take longer to get hot, then the device will fail. A heat sink (a misnomer) actually transfers the energy to the ambient environment. Thermal mass does not.